# comparing elements of the same array in java

Tags: java, arrays, compare, element, between

I am trying to compare elements of the same array. That means that i want to compare the 0 element with every other element, the 1 element with every other element and so on. The problem is that it is not working as intended. . What i do is I have two for loops that go from 0 to array.length-1.. Then i have an if statement that goes as follows: if(a[i]!=a[j+1])

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length - 1; k++) {
        if (a[i] != a[k + 1]) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " not the same with  " + a[k + 1] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First things first, you need to loop to `< a.length` rather than `a.length - 1`. As this is strictly less than you need to include the upper bound.

So, to check all pairs of elements you can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i] != a[k]) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But this will compare, for example `a[2]` to `a[3]` and then `a[3]` to `a[2]`. Given that you are checking `!=` this seems wasteful.

A better approach would be to compare each element `i` to the *rest of the array*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i] != a[k]) {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

So if you have the indices [1...5] the comparison would go

1. `1 -> 2`
2. `1 -> 3`
3. `1 -> 4`
4. `1 -> 5`
5. `2 -> 3`
6. `2 -> 4`
7. `2 -> 5`
8. `3 -> 4`
9. `3 -> 5`
10. `4 -> 5`

So you see pairs aren't repeated. Think of a circle of people all needing to shake hands with each other.

Comment: "That means that i want to compare the 0 element with every other element, the 1 element with every other element and so on."

The better approach might not be useful if he really wants ^

Comment: @Sumedh my first example does exactly that. I elaborate that given the comparison the OP is doing this might not be the best approach.

Comment: You don't need the `if (a[i] != a[k]) {` check.

Comment: @MarkKnol that's the whole _point_ of the exercise - of course you need it. The OP is checking each pair of elements for _non equal_ elements. Why? Only the OP knows that.

Comment: But if `k` starts at `i+1`, then there is never a equal element, or am I missing something? I get the same results without the condition.

Comment: @MarkKnol it's not `i != k` it's _`a[i] != a[k]`_ - i.e that the **array values** are not equal, not the indexes.

Comment: Ah thats the difference ofcourse. I assumed the array was unique already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this or purpose will solve with lesser no of steps

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
{
    for (int k = i+1; k < a.length; k++) 
    {
        if (a[i] != a[k]) 
         {
            System.out.println(a[i]+"not the same with"+a[k]+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you're not taking the last element into consideration at all...it should be "a.length" in inner loop

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i] != a[k]) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " not the same with  " + a[k + 1] + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

You can start from k=1 & keep "a.length-1" in outer for loop, in order to reduce two comparisions,but that doesnt make any significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

How can I compare the value of a[i] with a [a+1] and also with a[a-1] and also the value of the botton index ( related k)?
to find out if the value of current index is less than all other its neighbor

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i+1]) && (a[i] < a[i-1]) )  {
            int b = a[i]
        }
    }
}    
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
        if (a[k] < a[k+1]) && (a[k] < a[k-1]) )  {
            int c = a[k]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code. This logic will help to compare elements of an array.

```
    int[] arr= {1,7,22,55,22,6,6,7};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if(arr[i]==arr[j])
            {                   
                System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```