# HOW to compare all the elements of a matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix, compare

I've been trying for like a week, and i've found nothing that can help me out. Does someone know how to do it?
I need to compare each elements matrix and have an affirmative expression if there are not repeated numbers; and negative expression if there are repeated numbers.

my matrix is 3*3

THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [comparing elements of the same array in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460367/comparing-elements-of-the-same-array-in-java)

Comment: Can you show your matrice implementation ?

Comment: @PetterFriberg, as far I get, this question is about finding if _any_ elements are repeated.  The post you refer to checks if they're _all_ the same.  Different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if all elements of the matrix are equal you can try this code

```
int matrix[3][3];

int testMatrix(int* m, int size)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size * size; i++)
   {   
      for(int j = i + 1; j < size * size; j++)
         if(m[i] == m[j])
            return -1;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
testMatrix(&matrix[0][0], 3);
```

In memory your 3x3 matrix is looks the same as just array of 9 elements

Comment: If `testMatrix` is invoked as shown above, you'll get a compiler error about incompatible pointer types.

Comment: I fixed code. Instead of &matrix[0][0] you can also use reinterpret_cast<int*>(matrix) (C++ style) or just (int*)matrix (C style)